# Custom keyboard shortcuts

Tags: android, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut, ctrl

I want my app to support keyboard shortcuts. Many devices, such as `Asus Transformer` have external keyboard which has <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key (available on API Level 11). I've made some code, to check if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key works in emulator:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>10 &&
        event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
        event.isCtrlPressed()){
    String actionType="NONE";
    final int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
    switch(keyCode){
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_C:
        actionType = "COPY";
        break;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_V:
        actionType = "PASTE";
        break;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_X:
        actionType = "CUT";
        break;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_R:
        actionType = "REFRESH";
        break;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A:
        actionType = "SELECT ALL";
        break;
    }
    Toast.makeText(ctx, actionType, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work in emulator and I can't check it on real hardware.

I have two questions:
1. Would it work on device like `Asus Transformer`?
2. Why <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key does not work in emulator?

EDIT: I tried to find an answer or solution to my problem, but neither Google nor SO helped.

Comment: there is no CTRL key on most devices (at least not on most soft keyboards)

Comment: But what about hardware keyboards with CTRL key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **1. Would it work on device like Asus Transformer?**

I've checked on my *Asus Transformer TF101* with physical keyboard (standard docking station from *Asus*) and **your code works fine**. I think you can use it without problems.

> **2. Why CTRL key does not work in emulator?**

Looking at the [list of buttons that can be mapped](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html#KeyMapping) (for example using `emulator -keyset`) I don't think that current version of emulator supports direct `Ctrl` key mapping, so you're out of luck here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That's good news. I think that it's a good idea to add option to change the modifier key in order to provide support for everyone who has keyboard for Android device.