# How to intentionally go to new line in an EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am creating an app which provides chat functionality in it. There is an EditText in the screen, on which I have set OnKeyListener. Whenever user presses the "Enter" key after typing the message, the message is posted on the screen. It works fine. Here is my EditText:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/chatMessageField"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip" android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:maxLines="2" android:minLines="1" android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:hint="@string/chatMessageHintText" android:textColorHint="#3b64a8">
</EditText>
```

The problem is when user wants to go to new line before the EditText wraps the text and goes to new line. Now if user wants to go to new line and presses "Enter" key, the message is sent.

In some chat messangers , I have seen that pressing "Shift+Enter"(or any other key-combination) simultaneously takes the user to new line. How can we detect "Shift+Enter"(or any other key-combination) keys pressed simultaneously in Android? Is there any way to achieve this functionality in Android?

Answer (score 5):

Just try for this... It may help.

Set the input of EditText as

```
youredittext.setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
```

Then add:

```
android:singleLine="false"
```

or

```
youredittext.setSingleLine(false);
```

Also go [Click Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html)

Comment: It did help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In your `OnKeyListener` method, use check for `Enter` and `Shift Enter` and provide separate functionality of `Send` and `New Line` respectively.

Comment: How will I check for Shift and Enter button clicked simultaneously? Any code snippet?

Comment: `if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
   && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
 
   // your Send functionality
    return true;
 
 } else 
if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
   && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER 
     && keyCode == (KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT  ||KEYCODE_SHIFT_RIGHT ) )) {
 // / your New line functionality
return true;
}
` <br> Code is not compiled, may contain syntax error, presented for functionality. Instead of Shift, you can use LongPress for Enter as well to achieve 'new line' functionality'

Comment: For KeyEvent and long press event, refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Answer (score 1):

While searching you solution I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004344/android-edittext-imeoptions-done-track-finish-typing/5369989#5369989) link. Try it it may solve your problem.

And if some other best way you got please post, this is very useful and good question..,.

Thanks..,.

EDIT......................

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250563/custom-keyboard-shortcuts) link for better using the custom shortcuts..,.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can set 'OnKeyListener' method. For each key you can provide the functionality as follows..

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch(keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0:
            //handle code for pressing 0
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1
            //handles code for pressing 1
        default:
            break;
    }
}
});
```

**Just try to search the code for shift and enter**

It may Works.
Have fun.

Comment: dude I am not having fun !! I already know this. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: @YogeshSomani you want that if someone press enter with shift key then the newline should open. am i right?