# Register hardware keyboard shortcuts in Android's help menu

Tags: android, menu, keyboard-shortcuts, android-hardware-keyboard

Android supports external hardware keyboards as input, which may send keyboard shortcuts (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) in which there are some ways to program my app to accept shortcuts from external keyboards (e.g. like this: [Custom keyboard shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250563/custom-keyboard-shortcuts)).

I came across this keyboard shortcut "help" screen in Android (activated by pressing OS + /) (see picture below)

[image: Generic shortcut help screen] [image: App specific keyboard shortcut help screen]

and noticed some apps have some keyboard shortcuts directly **registered within the system** shortcuts help screen(these screens are not provided by the app, they can be found by pressing OS + /).

So far, the apps that I see that have this feature are:

- Samsung Internet
- Samsung One UI Home
- Google Chrome
- Chromium-based browsers (e.g. Brave)
- Google Docs, Sheets, Slides

I cannot find any way to register my keyboard shortcuts in my app programmatically such that they will be recognised by the system. How can I possibly implement it in my app?

I do know iOS/iPadOS has such a feature.

Perhaps Android does have such a feature too? It seems like it would be quite useful to app developers and users, not sure why it's not documented at all in Android Developer documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature is not documented in the Android Developer website, so I had to search around.

Since it is supported by AOSP, this is not a proprietary method/function by Google. No root is required on your users' devices.

Since this feature is available in Chromium-based browsers, I decided to check up the open-source Chromium Android source code (a mirror on GitHub is available here by someone: https://github.com/kuoruan/Chromium-Android) and I have discovered how this feature is implemented.

The relevant lines are here:

- https://github.com/kuoruan/Chromium-Android/blob/29ba2966ff145c9cb2492a971f9c03f879c5b9c9/app/src/main/java/org/chromium/chrome/browser/KeyboardShortcuts.java#L117
- https://github.com/kuoruan/Chromium-Android/blob/29ba2966ff145c9cb2492a971f9c03f879c5b9c9/app/src/main/java/org/chromium/chrome/browser/ChromeTabbedActivity.java#L2135

In any `Activity`, you can override the method `onProvideKeyboardShortcuts`.
It provides 3 parameters: `data`, `menu`, and `deviceId`, in which we only need `data` here.

Here is the method signature:

```java
fun onProvideKeyboardShortcuts(
        data: MutableList<KeyboardShortcutGroup>?,
        menu: Menu?,
        deviceId: Int
    )
```

**This only works on API 24 (Android Nougat) and above.**

`data` is a mutable list of `KeyboardShortcutGroup`, which is a group of keyboard shortcuts.

So, you can have multiple groups containing multiple shortcuts, useful for grouping the shortcuts for your users.

To register your shortcuts,

1. Create a `KeyboardShortcutGroup`. This is required to store and group your keyboard shortcuts together. The class accepts a `CharSequence` as a parameter for the name of the group, so you have to use `getString(R.string.your_resource)` for string resources.

```java
val keyboardShortcutGroup = KeyboardShortcutGroup(/* the name of your group here: */ "Test Group")
```

2. Define your keyboard shortcuts. Keyboard shortcuts are defined using `KeyboardShortcutInfo` objects, which accepts 3 parameters in it's constructor - a label, the key(e.g. A/ Z/ 8/ 9), and the modifier key. 
   A single keyboard shortcut is created this way:

```java
KeyboardShortcutInfo("Shortcut One" /*label*/, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Z/*key*/, KeyEvent.META_ALT_ON/*modifier*/)
```

You need to pass in key codes into the constructor for the key and the modifier key.
The key and modifier key must be passed in seperately.

Here are the list of available key codes:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#KEYCODE_0 (See those prefixed with `KEYCODE`)

Based on testing, the modifier keys which work are:

- Ctrl `META_CTRL_ON`
- Alt `META_ALT_ON`
- Shift `META_SHIFT_ON`
- Super/OS/Meta (see https://android.stackexchange.com/a/243218/307843) `META_META_ON`
- Function `META_FUNCTION_ON`
- Left/Right keys for all of these are also available(i.e. `META_ALT_LEFT_ON`)

`META_SYM_ON` may work(have not tested yet), but Caps Lock doesn't work.

To combine modifier keys,
in Java, use the bitwise operator:
`KeyEvent.META_ALT_LEFT_ON | KeyEvent.META_CTRL_ON`
in Kotlin, use the `or` operator:
`KeyEvent.META_ALT_LEFT_ON or KeyEvent.META_CTRL_ON`

3. To this `KeyboardShortcutGroup`, add shortcuts using `addItem`.

```java
keyboardShortcutGroup.addItem(shortcut /* <-- the shortcut created earlier */)
```

4. Add your `KeyboardShortcutGroup` to `data`

```java
data.add(keyboardShortcutGroup)
```

Your code should look like this:

```java
    override fun onProvideKeyboardShortcuts(
        data: MutableList<KeyboardShortcutGroup>?,
        menu: Menu?,
        deviceId: Int
    ) {
        super.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts(data, menu, deviceId)

        // Requires API 24
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {

            val keyboardShortcutGroup = KeyboardShortcutGroup("Test Group")
            keyboardShortcutGroup.addItem(KeyboardShortcutInfo("Shortcut One", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Z, KeyEvent.META_ALT_ON))
            data?.add(keyboardShortcutGroup)
        }
    }
```

You should see the end result:
[image: menu screenshot]

You can use this to inform users of available shortcuts. Note that this does not implement them, it merely adds a listing to the Android shortcut menu.